# Android: Custom Keyboard width increases automatically

Tags: android, keyboard, width

I am having a weird issue on emulator with ICS (but not on emulator with API level 21). I created a custom Keyboard:
[image: Normal]

Now whenever I tap a key, the width of the keyboard automatically increases a little bit. After hitting the keys several times, this is how it looks:

[image: After tapping number keys]

On the logcat I see "GC_FOR_ALLOC freed" every time i hit a key. I don't understand what is causing the width to increase.

The xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".SignInScreen">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="@dimen/companyImageWidth"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/companyLogo"/>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/marginUserListHor"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/marginUserListHor"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/marginUserListVer"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/marginUserListVer"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/usersList_signIn"/>
    </ScrollView>
    <com.ruach.pos.restaurant.MyKeyboardView
        android:id="@+id/passwordKeyboard"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:keyBackground="@drawable/keyboard_key_btn"
        android:keyTextColor="@color/black"
        android:shadowColor="@color/transparent"
        android:keyTextSize="@dimen/textSizeMed"
        android:labelTextSize="@dimen/textSizeMed"/>
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="numberPassword"
        android:id="@+id/userPasswordSignIn"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/passwordKeyboard"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/passwordKeyboard"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/marginPasswordField"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/marginPasswordField"
        android:layout_above="@+id/passwordKeyboard"
        android:textSize="@dimen/textSizeMed"
        android:background="@drawable/white_black_stroke_rect"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/usrPassPaddingLeft"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Keyboard xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Keyboard xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:keyWidth="6.5%p"
    android:keyHeight="6.5%p"
    android:horizontalGap="@dimen/keyboardKeysGap"
    android:verticalGap="@dimen/keyboardKeysGap">

    <Row>
        <Key android:codes="-1"    android:keyLabel="CLR" android:keyEdgeFlags="left"/>
        <Key android:codes="-2"    android:keyLabel="MOD"/>
        <Key android:codes="-3"    android:keyLabel="DEL" />
    </Row>
    <Row>

        <Key android:codes="55"    android:keyLabel="7"/>
        <Key android:codes="56"    android:keyLabel="8"/>
        <Key android:codes="57"    android:keyLabel="9" />
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Key android:codes="52"    android:keyLabel="4" />
        <Key android:codes="53"    android:keyLabel="5" />
        <Key android:codes="54"    android:keyLabel="6"/>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Key android:codes="49"    android:keyLabel="1"/>
        <Key android:codes="50"    android:keyLabel="2"/>
        <Key android:codes="51"    android:keyLabel="3" />
    </Row>


    <Row>
        <Key android:codes="48"    android:keyLabel="0" />
        <Key android:codes="-4"    android:keyLabel="00"/>
        <Key android:codes="66"    android:keyLabel="ENT" android:keyEdgeFlags="right"/>
    </Row>
</Keyboard>
```

Comment: Maybe it's the textbox that increases the size when you type and the keyboard just "follow". Show us your XML.

Comment: @VivekMishra code added

Comment: @AntónioPaulo i dont think so, i am having similar problem in another screen and in that screen i am not tapping number which would add any entry to EditText. Also, I have added the code.

Comment: add your keyboard xml too

Comment: @VivekMishra added

Comment: I also thinks this problem with increasing text size in edittext . Try giving it fixed width to check if that is the issue